# How to extract elements of a JSONB array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb, postgresql-10

Running PostgresSQL v10.5.

In my table `table_a` that has a column `metadata` which is of type `jsonb`.

It has a JSON array as one of it's keys `array_key` with value something like this:

```
[{"key1":"value11", "key2":"value21", "key3":"value31"}, 
 {"key1":"value21", "key2":"value22", "key3":"value23"}]
```

This is how I can query this key

```
SELECT metadata->>'array_key' from table_a
```

This gives me the entire array. Is there any way I can query only selected keys and perhaps format them?

The type of the array is text i.e `pg_typeof(metadata->>'array_key')` is `text`

An ideal output would be

```
"value11, value13", "value21, value23"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to get elements of the array (as `value`) which can be filtered by keys:

```
select value->>'key1' as key1, value->>'key3' as key3
from table_a
cross join jsonb_array_elements(metadata->'array_key');

  key1   |  key3   
---------+---------
 value11 | value31
 value21 | value23
(2 rows)
```

Use an aggregate to get the output as a single value for each row, e.g.:

```
select string_agg(concat_ws(', ', value->>'key1', value->>'key3'), '; ')
from table_a
cross join jsonb_array_elements(metadata->'array_key')
group by id;

             string_agg             
------------------------------------
 value11, value31; value21, value23
(1 row)
```

[Working example in rextester.](http://rextester.com/WQJN68238)